# Is it safe to share my signed transaction publicly?

Tags: security, raw-transaction

If someone got hold of my Ethereum signed transaction, is my wallet still safe?
Can they extract the raw transaction from the signed transaction to get my private key?

Answer (score 2):

Signing a transaction is a one way cryptographic operation.  The private key cannot be derived from the signature. Moreover, the signature must be readable because it verifies you are the creator of the transaction.  Also, all transactions are public. So, yes your wallet is safe.